Can I install in TeXlive the full-scheme and the collection "context and packages" after i already downloaded the medium-scheme?
I installed texlive and lyx a while ago with the medium scheme and without the collection "context and packages", I did it following a guide for downloading LyX in Hebrew and it works almost perfectly
I only have a very specific problem that the instant preview environment doesn't work when I put an ERT environment inside of it, to render TeX code inside the LyX document itself, after some help from the lyx mailing list we understood it's a configuration problem (I have all required packages it's just the preview doesn't even try to do anything - according to the log files) so the only thing that I did in installation that was deviating from the default installation was in the texlive installation I chose the medium scheme instead of the full one and I unchecked the collection "context and packages".
so now I wonder if downloading them will solve this problem without introducing new problems?
so my question is "will downloading the full scheme or the collection 'context and packages' or both result in some conflict or some new problem or will change how things are currently configured?"
I can't allow myself to test it since I work daily on lyx and any debugging right now will take crucial time out of my learning time.
and btw I cant find the collection "context and packages" in the texlive shell, how would I download it if I wanted to?
using Windows 10, and latest versions of LyX and texlive

I don't think lyx can use ConTeXt - I doubt that installing ConTeXt will influence the lyx preview.

@daleif I'm cleaning up my comments after the edit

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz No it's in Windows 10, forgot to mention it, updated the question with this

@Nate3384 Thanks for the clarification!

you can use tlmgr to add or remove packages, collections or whatever. you won't create conflicts (to the best of my knowledge). installing a scheme is just a way of installing a bunch of collections (on top of the basics) and installing a collection is just a way of installing a bunch of packages. full is a superset of medium. just make sure you update everything afterwards so you don't have a mix of newer and older. I don't know if you can do this using the GUI for tlmgr as I've never used it. but you can use tlmgr  on the command line. no idea if this will upset lyx in any way.

@cfr i can download the full scheme form the GUI but not the "context and packages" but if I understood your explanation it's already included in the full scheme

tlmgr info --list schemes -> i scheme-full: full scheme (everything)
